# change R.string.name to a variable

Tags: android

my problem is how to set a variable in R.string.(variable) instead of R.string.song?

**string.xml**

```
<string name="song">song title</string>
```

**java code**

if I do like this

```
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

tv.setText(R.string.song);
```

it works fine but if I change the reference name to a variable...

```
String selectedsong = "song title";

TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

tv.setText(R.string.selectedsong);
```

it gets me an error... can I change that reference name to a variable or not? i am new in this. thanks

Comment: Have u a string named : selectedsong ? <string name="selectedsong ">here</string>

Comment: selectedsong not exist in string.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is not stored in R.string, but rather in the local scope.

Change

```
tv.setText(R.string.selectedsong);
```

to

```
tv.setText(selectedsong);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need the [`getIdentifier()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method, which will give you the correct integer, that represents the `R.string.<selectedsong>` identifier.